# React native about e.nativeEvent point in Parent Responder and Child Responder

Tags: react-native

## code

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View
        onStartShouldSetResponder={(e)=>{
          console.log('parent line',e.nativeEvent.locationX)
          return true
        }}
        style={{width:300,height:20,backgroundColor:'green'}}
      >
         <View 
           onStartShouldSetResponder={(e)=>{
             console.log('child point',e.nativeEvent.locationX)
             return false//make the parent can also respond to the touch event
           }}

           style={{marginLeft:50,width:20,height:20,borderRadius:10,backgroundColor:'white'}}
         />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

## Overview

[touch parent line view](https://luokun.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/QQ%E6%88%AA%E5%9B%BE20190322220840.png)

[touch child point view](https://luokun.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/QQ%E6%88%AA%E5%9B%BE20190322220742.png)

If I only touch the `Parent Line View`,`onStartShouldSetResponder`event.nativeEvent.locationX is truely where I touch's position. Maybe 299 or 0

If I touch the `Child Point View`,and console the `Child Point View` and `Parent Line View`'s `nativeEvent.locationX`, they are the same but they are all base on `Child Point View` area.

Let me put it another way, the result must be less than 50 alse must be less than 20,Obviously not what I wanted for `Parent Line View` **locationX**.

**Why**?

Comment: Are you asking why the PanResponder system is using relative coordinates or do you actually have a problem which needs to be solved?

Comment: It is a problem for me.I want to get `Parent Line View`'s relative coordinates in real time whatever I touch `Parent Line View` or `Child Point View`. [See the detail in a gif ](https://luokun.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/3%E6%9C%88-23-2019%2012-41-35.gif)

Answer (score 0):

## This demo can clearly explain this problem

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state={
    left:0
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center'}}>
                <View
                    onStartShouldSetResponder={(e)=>{
                        console.log('parent line',e.nativeEvent.locationX,e)
                        this.setState({left:e.nativeEvent.locationX})
                        return true
                    }}
                    onResponderMove={(e)=>{
                        console.log('move',e.nativeEvent)
                        this.setState({left:e.nativeEvent.locationX})
                    }}
                    style={{width:'100%',height:20,justifyContent:'center',backgroundColor:'green'}}
                >
                    <View
                        onStartShouldSetResponder={(e)=>{
                            console.log('child point',e.nativeEvent.locationX,e)
                            return false
                        }}
                        onMoveShouldSetResponder={(e)=>{
                            return false
                        }}
                        style={{position:'absolute',left:this.state.left,height:20,width:20,borderRadius:10,backgroundColor:'#fff'}}
                    />

                </View>
            </View>
    )
  }
}
```

[Demo Preview gif](https://luokun.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/3%E6%9C%88-23-2019%2012-41-35.gif)